# Setup Mock for Update function (CRUD)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I try to Setup a mock for Update function,

```
public class JelentkezokService : IJelentkezokService
{
    IJelentkezokRepository JelentkezokRepository { get; set; }

    public Jelentkezok Update(Jelentkezok jelentkezo)
    {
        if (JelentkezokRepository.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id == jelentkezo.Id))
        {
            return JelentkezokRepository.Update(jelentkezo);
        }
        //The ID is not exist
        else throw new Exception($"A megadott jelentkező ID nem létezik: {jelentkezo.Id}");
    }
}
```

testing whether the function was called but it goes for the exception in the Service. Any idea?

```
[TestFixture]
public class JelentkezokBLTests
{
    Mock<IJelentkezokRepository> JelentkezokRepositoryMock;

    [Test]
    public void JelentkezokUpdateMeghivva()
    {
        //Arrange
        JelentkezokRepositoryMock = new Mock<IJelentkezokRepository>();

        var input = new DA.Jelentkezok()
        {
            Id = 13,
            Nev = "Kis Béla",
            Varos = "Győr",
            Utca = "Kodály Zoltán u. 15.",
            SzuletesiDatum = new DateTime(1982, 11, 19),
            Iranyitoszam = 9030,
            Ferfi = true,
        };
        var mockedResult = new DA.Jelentkezok()
        {
            Id = 13,
            Nev = "Kis Anita",
            Varos = "Győr",
            Utca = "Kodály Zoltán u. 15.",
            SzuletesiDatum = new DateTime(1982, 11, 19),
            Iranyitoszam = 9030,
            Ferfi = false,
        };

        JelentkezokRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Update(input)).Returns(mockedResult);

        JelentkezokService service = new JelentkezokService(JelentkezokRepositoryMock.Object);
        //Act
        var updateJelentkezo = service.Update(input);

        //Assert
        //Assert.That(input, Is.Not.Null);
        JelentkezokRepositoryMock.Verify(v => v.Update(input), Times.AtLeastOnce);

}
```

I have the error 
Message: System.Exception : A megadott jelentkező ID nem létezik: 13 //The ID is not exist.

Comment: Nkosi is right, that GetAll definitely needs mocking. However you might also consider using something more like .Find and != null, instead of .GetAll.Any in your repository, assuming Id is the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `JelentkezokRepository.GetAll()` is not behaving as expected.

Assuming it returns a collection

```
IEnumerable<Jelentkezok> GetAll();
```

That may need to be setup as well.

```
//...

var item = new DA.Jelentkezok() {
    Id = 13,            
};
var all = new [] { item };

JelentkezokRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(all);

//...
```

In order to allow the `if` condition to flow as expected when the test is exercised.